# How to fix OpenCV using multiple cameras on PCIe card returning a black frame?

Tags: python, opencv

I'm using python OpenCV on a Windows 10 computer to process the frames from USB cameras. When running the cameras off of a PCIe USB card, VideoCapture.read() returns appropriately-sized, black frames most of the time and occasionally reads the correct image.

I've already tested running the cameras off of a USB hub and found that the hub would result in connection errors. For this reason I moved to running the cameras off of a USB 3.0 PCIe card which should have more than enough speed to collect the frames from all of the cameras (especially shown by the fact that decreasing the frame rate leads to no improvement).

My code looks like this:

```py
import cv2

code_should_be_running = True  # boolean to shut the loop down externally
camera = cv2.VideoCapture(0)  # OpenCV camera connection handle


while code_should_be_running:
    read_success, frame = camera.read()  # where the frames are returned black

    if read_success:
        processed_frame = process_frame(frame)  # OpenCV-based processing of frame
        cv2.imshow('Window Name', processed_frame)
        cv2.waitKey(1)
```

I'm positive that this is not an issue at the python level (though I guess a workaround could still be at this level). This is because when stepping through the code, the frames are simply returned black at the location indicated by the comment in the code and the processing has nothing to do with it.

I expect this is related to OpenCV's dealing with how connections are held to USB cameras. I thought however that a PCIe card would expand the ability of OpenCV to use cameras simultaneously. The bandwidth can't be the problem here because the PCIe card is rated for more frames than these cameras could possible produce at full speed. Also, when I was testing the USB hub, I would get actual connection errors while this doesn't give connection errors it just returns a black (0 values) frame.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an answer and I'll add it here for documentation purposes. This is a little outside my range of experience so feel free to comment on improper lingo or incorrect assumptions.

OpenCV locks a channel on a USB controller for use with VideoCapture. Any other VideoCapture object that tries to communicate through that channel will have communication problems (though not other non-OpenCV devices as long as that communication path has the bandwidth). A given motherboard has so many channels for its USB connections. The PCIe card that I had, while having 4 ports, only added one channel. You can buy PCIe cards that add more than one channel. You must make sure that no VideoCapture handle uses the same channel.

Playing around with it, I wanted a way to identify what channel a USB port was using when I plug in the camera so that I could identify if a camera would cause problems where it was plugged in. I'm not sure the best way of doing this but one thing I did notice is that if you go to (Windows 10) Device Manager -> Universal Serial Bus controllers ->  -> Details tab -> Property: Location Paths the PCI value in parentheses would would be unique with a USB controller.

Ex: PCIROOT(0)#PCI(**1C00**)#PCI(0000)#PCI(0100)#PCI(0000)#PCI(0400)#PCI(0000)#PCI(0100)#PCI(0000)#USBROOT(0)#USB(3)#USB(5)

Thus, if that value didn't match any other VideoCapture device, it would not have problems.

Of course, you could always switch to Ethernet cameras for multi-camera set ups which I believe is the current recommended method. But I leave this here for anyone that needs it.